# Implicit search inside macro expansion fails

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Consider a trait that performs "encoding" of arbitrary objects:

```scala
trait Encoder[R] {
  def encode(r: R): Array[Byte]
}
```

Assuming encoding of primitive types is known and custom types can be encoded by defining up a "serializer":

```scala
trait Serializer[T] {
  def serialize(r: T): Array[Byte]
}
```

we can implement a macro for case class encoding by simply looping the fields and looking up type serializers implicitly. Here's a dummy implementation that looks up the serializer for `R` itself (in reality we look up serializers for case class field types):

```
object Encoder {
  implicit def apply[R <: Product]: Encoder[R] = macro applyImpl[R]
  def applyImpl[R: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Encoder[R]] = {
    import c.universe._
    c.Expr[Encoder[R]](q"""
      new ${weakTypeOf[Encoder[R]]} {
        override def encode(r: ${weakTypeOf[R]}): Array[Byte] = 
          implicitly[_root_.Serializer[${weakTypeOf[R]}]].serialize(r)
        }
    """)
  }
}
```

Now define a base "processor":

```scala
abstract class BaseProcessor[R: Encoder] {
  def process(r: R): Unit = {
    println(implicitly[Encoder[R]].encode(r).length)
  }
}
```

And try to use it:

```
case class Record(i: Int)

object Serializers {
  implicit def recordSerializer: Serializer[Record] = 
    (r: Record) => Array.emptyByteArray
}

import Serializers._

class Processor extends BaseProcessor[Record]
```

This fails to compile with:

```
// [error] Loader.scala:10:22: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Serializer[Record]
// [error] class Processor extends BaseProcessor[Record]
// [error]                         ^
// [error] one error found
```

However the following do compile:

```scala
class Processor extends BaseProcessor[Record]()(Encoder[Record]) // Compiles!
object x { class Processor extends BaseProcessor[Record] }       // Compiles!
```

I can't really understand why this happens, looks like it has something to do with the `Processor` definition being a top level definition, since as soon as I move it inside a class/object everything works as expected. Here's one more example that fails to compile:

```
object x {
  import Serializers._ // moving the import here also makes it NOT compile
  class Processor extends BaseProcessor[Record] 
}
```

Why does this happen and is there any way to make it work?

Comment: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/implicit-search-inside-macro-expansion-fails/4551

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you can try one of the following:

1) add context bound

```
implicit def apply[R <: Product : Serializer]: Encoder[R] = macro applyImpl[R]

def applyImpl[R: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)(serializer: c.Expr[Serializer[R]]): c.Expr[Encoder[R]] = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr[Encoder[R]](q"""
    new Encoder[${weakTypeOf[R]}] {
      override def encode(r: ${weakTypeOf[R]}): Array[Byte] =
        $serializer.serialize(r)
    }
  """)
}
```

2) make macro `whitebox`

3) put implicit instance `recordSerializer: Serializer[Record]` to the companion object of `Record` rather than some object `Serializers` to be imported

4) maybe your example is easier than actual use case but now it seems you don't need macros

```
implicit def apply[R <: Product : Serializer]: Encoder[R] = new Encoder[R] {
  override def encode(r: R): Array[Byte] = implicitly[Serializer[R]].serialize(r)
}
```